# What does "leap off" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

In this sentence, "Over the years, they’d built snow forts
together and leaped off backyard sheds together" what does "leap off" mean?

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you found 'leap' in a dictionary?

Comment: Of course I've checked the dictionary. It says leap means jump. But in this sentence I'm not sure if they jump in, or out, or over the sheds or what...

Comment: How do you imagine someone might jump **off** a shed?

Comment: Are they on top of the roof?

Comment: Most likely. (When asking questions here, it's a good idea to explain that you know the usual meaning of a word but are puzzled by a particular context.)

Comment: Are you asking if *off* means "in, out, over"? No, but you may be stuck thinking that a shed is a storehouse, when it can be a little thing like a doghouse.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context more fully, this is a bit of a guess, but here goes:

The fact that the phrase describes the people building snow forts together leads me to think the entire description is during winter. Given the right conditions, snow can form a soft surface to jump onto.

The sentence definitely means the people jumped off the shed roof onto the ground together, but may imply that it was done into a snow pack for cushioning or lessened distance to fall. This is an activity children, in testing their daring, engage in. The passage therefore describes bonding through exciting activity.

Comment: Hello, kaipmdh. Please take a tour of the site, visit the Help Center, and make an assessment of the standard of questions ELU is intended to address. This question is one most 12-year-old native speakers would be expected to know how to answer. It is off-topic, especially as no reasonable research is added. It should be close-voted rather than answered.

Comment: Hello, Edwin. While I agree with you that the level of language was not especially challenging here, I thought the cultural particularity of jumping into snowdrifts may have warranted an explanation. No skin off my back answering it.

Comment: (1) The question was about 'leap off' in general. There's no guarantee that the author was saying that the jumping off shed roofs happened when there was snow. (2) Social bonding as a result is a totally separate issue, not relevant when  word meaning is being asked about.  (3) In any case, such writing analysis is off-topic on ELU. // Answering off-topic questions _does_ have a negative effect on the site – it encourages further such questions, obscuring ELU's aims. Which are clearly stated at the Help Center.